# editing 'config false' leaf in YANG

Tags: config, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

How do I change 'config false' leafs and update the values in my server so when a client make get-config command he will get the updated value?

```
leaf state {
  type enumeration {
    enum DISABLED {
      description
        "array carrier is not active - transmission of signal is disabled.";
    }
    enum BUSY {
      description
        "array carrier is processing an operation requested by change of active parameter.
        When array carriers is BUSY the transmission of signal is not guaranteed.";
    }
    enum READY {
      description
        "array carrier had completed activation operation - is active and transmission of signal is ongoing.";
    }
  }
  config false;
  mandatory true;
  description
    "Indicates state of array carriers activation operation";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hy

A YANG paramenter with config-false set to true can be modified not by direct user/api input.

You must implement service logic within your app that modify that parameter after a certain triggher or event.

Config-false option has been created in order to avoid value modification triggered by input events. See RFC YANG 1.1 for more information.